# After executing following code of dockerode npm getting error "connect EACCES /var/run/docker.sock" on ubuntu 14.04

Tags: node.js, docker, ubuntu

I am executing following code to get list of all container using npm dockerode on Ubuntu 14.04 machine. Docker container are running properly.

```
var Docker = require('dockerode');
var docker = new Docker({socketPath: '/var/run/docker.sock'});

docker.listContainers({all: true}, function(err, containers) {
console.log('err ' + err);
console.log('ALL: ' + containers);
});
```

But getting

> Error connect EACCES /var/run/docker.sock

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This happens because you don't have sufficient permissions to access Docker. There are two solutions:

1. Run the command with sudo. (not recommended)
2. Add current user to the `docker` group using this command:

   ```
   $ sudo usermod -aG docker $USER
   $ newgrp docker
   ```

Logout and log back in once you run this command and try running your code again. (recommended)

Comment: Remember that the ability to run any Docker commands at all implies unlimited root access on the host; requiring `sudo` for it is not actually a bad idea.

Comment: @DavidMaze Agreed. But it becomes a little cumbersome to use sudo and enter the password repeatedly. Adding user to the group is a more elegant method.

Answer (score 17):

For security-wise, I go pro for [GreatDharmatma](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3698225/greatdharmatma) and [Pankaj Kumar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3782093/pankaj-kumar).

If you want to skip the logging back and access instantly you can assign `rw` permission to `other users`

```sh
sudo chmod o+rw /var/run/docker.sock
```

Comment: Thank you, This works in the VS code docker extension (permission denied issue)

Answer (score 2):

Without changing the socket rights maybe just creating a new user `node` for nodejs then add him to the `docker` group

`sudo useradd -g node docker`