# Dockerode can not get list of running containers

Tags: docker, linux-mint, dockerode

I'm trying to get the list of containers using Dockerode + Javascript code. Although I can see containers running in Docker Desktop, Dockerode doesn't seem to pick up the list of containers. I've tried the fix in this thread: [After executing following code of dockerode npm getting error "connect EACCES /var/run/docker.sock" on ubuntu 14.04](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52364905), but it doesn't seem to work. I'm running Linux Mint Debian edition.

Anybody knows anything about this issue? Anywhere I should look?